# SQL many-to-many get all from a table

Tags: sql, postgresql, many-to-many

I have three tables:

1. users

| id | some_user_data | some_more_user_data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ... | ... |
| 2 | ... | ... |
| 3 | ... | ... |

2. classrooms

| id | some_classroom_data | some_more_classroom_data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ... | ... |
| 2 | ... | ... |
| 3 | ... | ... |

3. classroom_users

| id | user_id | classroom_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 3 | 1 |
| 5 | 3 | 2 |

I need a query that, given a user_id, can get all the data for all the classrooms that particular user is in. So, if I ran the query on the tables above given a user_id of 1, I want to get back the following result:

| id | some_classroom_data | some_more_classroom_data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ... | ... |
| 3 | ... | ... |

Thanks in advance for your help. I have been trying to wrap my mind around this SQL query for far too long.

FYI, I am using Postgres.

Comment: if you are not interested in user data (table 1) then simply join last 2 tables on class_room_id

Comment: Thank you. I was way overthinking it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help

```
select c.* from classroom_users cu, classrooms c
where cu.user_id = <input user id> and cu.classroom_id = c.id;
```

Comment: Thanks. I was way overthinking the problem. Thanks for correcting me with this solution